# Python function returns only the first value instead of a dataframe

Tags: python, function, dataframe, return, portfolio

I have build a function where I append the returns of 5 portfolios to a dataframe which I want to return to a variable . When I run the commands within the function row by row(kind of debugging) I end upwith the variable 'folioReturn'(which is the one I want my script to return) having the right amount of values (e.x 5). But if I call the function, only the first value of the dataframe is returned. Does anyone know how I can get the whole dataframe ?

```
def portfolioReturns (securities, quintilesNo, perReturns):
    '''
    this function receives 
    1)securities: array with the security names and values ** for the purpose of our work the names
    should already be sorted
    2)quintilesNo: the number of portfolios we want to create 
    3)perReturns: an array with the returns that will be used for performance measuremnt

    It returns an array with the returns for each portfolio

    '''

    # we calculate the number of securities per portfolio 
    stdFolioSize = np.divmod(securities.size, quintilesNo)[0] # we take the floor division
    folioReturn = [] # pd.DataFrame()
    # we create portfolios with equal number of securities except of the last one where we use all the remaining securities
    for k in range(0, quintilesNo, 1): # in folio list we store the name of the securities we must include in each portfolio
        if k < (quintilesNo - 1):           
            folioList = securities.index.get_level_values(1)[k * stdFolioSize : (k + 1) * stdFolioSize]

        else: # the last portfolio will also include the remainder securities 
            folioList = securities.index.get_level_values(1)[k * stdFolioSize : securities.size]

        # now that we have the list of the securities to be included in the folio, we use the table
        # with the periodical returns to check the performance. The portfolio we construct is equally weighted

        # first we drop one index(the first index of the country) and then we store all the periodical returns in one-array 
        perRetFinalTable = pd.DataFrame(perReturns.reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)).T  

        # using the list of the bonds we want to include in our portfolio we pick the bond returns and
        # we store them in one array. Then we calculate the folio return
        folio = perRetFinalTable[folioList]
        folioReturn = np.append(folioReturn, folio.sum(axis = 1) * (1 / folio.size))
        folioReturn = pd.DataFrame(folioReturn).T
        # folioReturn = pd.Series(folioReturn).T

        return (folioReturn)
```

Comment: Your `return` statement is inside of the for-loop, which promptly ends when that statement exits the function. And thus, only the first loop of the for-loop is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return statement must be after the for loop if you want whole list in your case during the first loop only the value is returned.
just remove the return from for loop it will work fine.

```
def portfolioReturns (securities, quintilesNo, perReturns):
    '''
    this function receives 
    1)securities: array with the security names and values ** for the purpose of our work the names
    should already be sorted
    2)quintilesNo: the number of portfolios we want to create 
    3)perReturns: an array with the returns that will be used for performance measuremnt

    It returns an array with the returns for each portfolio

    '''

    # we calculate the number of securities per portfolio 
    stdFolioSize = np.divmod(securities.size, quintilesNo)[0] # we take the floor division
    folioReturn = [] # pd.DataFrame()
    # we create portfolios with equal number of securities except of the last one where we use all the remaining securities
    for k in range(0, quintilesNo, 1): # in folio list we store the name of the securities we must include in each portfolio
        if k < (quintilesNo - 1):           
            folioList = securities.index.get_level_values(1)[k * stdFolioSize : (k + 1) * stdFolioSize]

        else: # the last portfolio will also include the remainder securities 
            folioList = securities.index.get_level_values(1)[k * stdFolioSize : securities.size]

        # now that we have the list of the securities to be included in the folio, we use the table
        # with the periodical returns to check the performance. The portfolio we construct is equally weighted

        # first we drop one index(the first index of the country) and then we store all the periodical returns in one-array 
        perRetFinalTable = pd.DataFrame(perReturns.reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)).T  

        # using the list of the bonds we want to include in our portfolio we pick the bond returns and
        # we store them in one array. Then we calculate the folio return
        folio = perRetFinalTable[folioList]
        folioReturn = np.append(folioReturn, folio.sum(axis = 1) * (1 / folio.size))
        folioReturn = pd.DataFrame(folioReturn).T
        # folioReturn = pd.Series(folioReturn).T

    return (folioReturn)
```

Comment: This will only change the output to the _last_ value in the loop, because he's overwriting `folioReturn` inside of the loop.

Comment: thanks  @HampusLarsson yes you are correct  i missed that point, so he also needs to append it in folioReturn new values.

Comment: guys...thank you very much. I bit stupid of me....next time I will make sure to post something more serious

Answer (score 1):

You're basically exiting the function too early.

Here are two examples to make it simpler to follow along:

```
def test():
    lst = []
    for num in range(10):
        lst = num
        return lst

def test2():
    lst = []
    for num in range(10):
        lst.append(num)
    return lst

print(test()) # Output: 0
print(test2()) # Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In `test` we create a list-variable called `lst`, then inside of a for-loop, we overwrite `lst` with the current variable `num` and then immediately issue a `return` statement, which only returns `0` because it's the first entry in the for-loop.

In `test2` we do the same thing in the start of the loop, however, instead of overwriting `lst` we instead use the method `list.append()` which adds the value of `num` to the already created list.

After we're then done with the whole for-loop, we then use the `return` statement to give back the variable `lst` which now contains all the values from `0` to `9`.

---

EDIT: It seems I failed to address the *actual* problem in your code. There are two major errors:

- You're exiting your for-loop using the `return` statement because it's inside of the for-loop. Fix the indentation, and that should be resolved.
- Inside of your for-loop, you're overwriting `folioReturn` instead of appending the values calculated inside of the for-loop to it. Replace the variable `folioReturn` inside of the for-loop, and then after you've created the `DataFrame`, append that value to `folioReturn`.